# What's the smallest $\lambda$-calculus term not known to have a normal form?

Tags: lo.logic, lambda-calculus

For Turing Machines, the question of halting behavior of small TMs has been well studied in the context of the Busy Beaver function, which maps n to the longest output or running time of any halting n state TM. The smallest TM with unknown halting behavior has 5 states. It takes $5\cdot2\cdot\log_2(5\cdot4 + 4)$ or roughly 46 bits to describe, 50 bits if we assume a straightforward encoding.

In comparison, $\lambda$-calculus terms have a [simple binary encoding](http://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html): $00$ for lambda, $01$ for application, and $1^n0$ for variable with de Bruijn index $n$. It's natural to define a $\lambda$-calculus analog of the busy beaver function as the maximum normal form size of any size $n$ closed lambda term.

As the smallest closed lambda term is $\lambda\,1$, with encoding $0010$, we determine
$$
BB_{\lambda}(4) = 4
$$
The next smallest ones, $\lambda\,\lambda\,1$ and $\lambda\,\lambda\,2$ are similarly already in normal form, and give
$$
BB_{\lambda}(6) = 6,\qquad BB_{\lambda}(7) = 7
$$
$BB_{\lambda}(n)$ will have to remain undefined for $n < 4$ or $n = 5$.

The first enlarged normal form shows up at $\lambda\,(\lambda\,1\,1)\,(1\,(\lambda\,2))$ which gives
$$
BB_{\lambda}(21) = 22
$$
$BB_{\lambda}$ starts to grow rapidly at $n \geq 30$, since tripling Church numeral two, $(\lambda\,1\,1\,1)\,(\lambda\,\lambda\,2\,(2\,1))$ with normal form Church numeral $2^{2^2}= 16$, gives
$$
BB_{\lambda}(30) \geq 5 \cdot 16 + 6 = 86
$$
and quadrupling/quintupling give
$$
BB_{\lambda}(34) \geq 5 \cdot 2^{16} + 6
$$
$$
BB_{\lambda}(38) \geq 5 \cdot 2^{2^{16}} + 6
$$
which exceed the TM Busy Beavers for 4 and 5 states.

An Ackermann-like function takes a mere [29 bits](https://github.com/tromp/AIT/blob/master/fast_growing_and_conjectures/ackermann.lam).
A twisted application to Church numeral $2$ yields a $BB_{\lambda}(51)$ exceeding 2↑↑↑↑5.

Graham's number is exceeded in at most [63 bits](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:JohnTromp/The_largest_number_representable_in_64_bits#Lambda_Calculus), giving
$$
BB_{\lambda}(63) \geq 5 \cdot G + 6
$$
(compared with a 16 state TM that needs over 192 bits to describe).

What's the smallest n for which $BB_{\lambda}(n)$ is unknown in ZFC?

One upper bound is [213 bits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79620/laver-table-computations-and-an-algorithm-that-is-not-known-to-terminate-in-zfc).

Let's try to narrow it down some more.

Function $BB_{\lambda}$ has been added to the [Online Encyclopedia for Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A333479).

Comment: Are all those slashes supposed to represent lambda?

Comment: Yes, they were. I replaced them by actual lambdas now.

Comment: Shouldn't $\lambda 1$ have encoding `00110` (of length five), or am I missing something in the notation here?

Comment: When i changed from 0-based to 1-based variables, I forgot to update the encoding. It's fixed now.

Comment: It seems that application is also the other way round... quoting [yourself](https://tromp.github.io/cl/Binary_lambda_calculus.html#Lambda_encoding) :-)

Comment: oops; good catch! will fix right away.

Comment: Curiously, triple Church_2 is not the best 30 bit beaver. A very minor tweak gives a 160 bit normal form!

Comment: For an upper bound, do you know what a lambda calculus formulation of twin primes / Goldbach / similar number-theoretic statements might look like?

Comment: Yes; Goldbach is 267 bits, as can be seen at https://github.com/tromp/AIT/blob/master/goldbach.gif which is compiled from goldbach.lam; larger than the 213 bit Laver statement above.

Comment: I also have an upper bound of 247 bits for finding an odd perfect number at https://github.com/tromp/AIT/blob/master/oddperfect.lam

Comment: By “not known to halt”, do you mean “unknown halting behavior” or “known to not halt or unknown halting behavior”?

Comment: I mean "unknown halting behaviour". We know that (\ 1 1)(\ 1 1) is the smallest nonhalting term, of size 18.

Comment: Does "unknown" mean "unknown in ZFC"? I infer that this is the case from the upper bound being a reference to a program which is known to halt under the assumption of a rank-into-rank cardinal.

Comment: Yes, I meant unknown in ZFC. I'll make that explicit.